# FuncAnimation, No Animation is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I wrote the following code in python3 to display projectile motion with some cool animations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Function to calculate projectile motion
def projectile_motion(t, v0, theta):
    g = 9.8  # acceleration due to gravity
    x = v0 * np.cos(theta) * t
    y = v0 * np.sin(theta) * t - 0.5 * g * t**2
    return x, y

# Function to update the plot during animation
def update(frame):
    t = frame / 10.0  # adjust the time scale
    x, y = projectile_motion(t, v0, theta)
    trajectory.set_data([x], [y])  # Pass arrays with a single element for x and y
    return trajectory,

# Set up the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

# Initial conditions
v0 = 10.0  # initial velocity
theta = np.radians(45)  # launch angle

# Plot the initial trajectory
t_init = np.linspace(0, 2 * v0 * np.sin(theta) / 9.8, 100)
x_init, y_init = projectile_motion(t_init, v0, theta)
trajectory, = ax.plot(x_init, y_init, 'b-')

# Set up the animation
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, interval=50, blit=True)

# Display the animation
plt.show()
```

Yet when I run it I see only white plot, what is that?

I tried changing frames / interval but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you trying to plot points or a line? As is, your code is trying to plot a line but you are only providing a single x value and a single y value, so there is no line to be drawn. When drawing a line in an animation you would typically generate all the data beforehand and then slice the data when passing it to `add_data`. So, you would have a `x` and `y` arrays with all data for all frames and then in the `update` function you'd have `.set_data(x[:frame], y[:frame])`, which provides all the data up to `frame`.